# ecj - Evolve kills all thread after completing calculation

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I use ecj package (https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/) for genetic algorithms. When I run the following code, it automatically shutdowns all threads so I can't run anything after calculation.

```
Evolve e = new Evolve();
e.main(arg);
```

When I try to use it within tomcat, after calculation it kills all threads even tomcat itself.

Could you suggest any solution, please?